# Interval in a table does not match interval in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, intervals

I would like to compare 'from-to" values of a table with another table values and see if they match. Actually, I want the FROM of the first table to fit to one of the FROM of the other table and the TO of the first table to fit one of the TO of the second table as in:

```
     TABLE1                                TABLE2
GEOLFROM GEOLTO                         SAMPFROM SAMPLTO
   28.5    36                             28.5   29.5
                                          29.5   32
                                          32     34.5
                                          34.5   36.1
                                          36.1   38
```

In that scenario I would like an error message since there is no match for the geolto of table 1.

```
DECLARE @COUNT_ int
SELECT @COUNT_ = COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.HOLEID = T2.HOLEID AND (T1.GEOLFROM = T2.SAMPFROM OR T1.GEOLTO = T2.SAMPTO) 

IF COUNT > 0 
    [...] ERROR
```

Comment: Where are your users going to see the error message?

Comment: Stop counting - you only need to check for existence. And we see your sample query refers to columns that do not exist in your sample tables - so obviously there is more to this issue than you describe. That is why it is best to post a short script containing DDL and DML to populate sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have two values that can show up in any 2 different rows I believe you have to JOIN twice on the same table.  So here is what I believe will work for you:

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl_1(HoleID int, GEOLFROM decimal(10,1), GEOLTO decimal(10,1))
CREATE TABLE #tbl_2(HoleID int, SAMPFROM decimal(10,1), SAMPTO decimal(10,1))

INSERT INTO #tbl_1 VALUES(1,28.5,36)
INSERT INTO #tbl_2 VALUES(1,28.5,29.5)
INSERT INTO #tbl_2 VALUES(1,29.5,32)
INSERT INTO #tbl_2 VALUES(1,32,34.5)
INSERT INTO #tbl_2 VALUES(1,34.5,36.1)
INSERT INTO #tbl_2 VALUES(1,36.1,38)

SELECT COUNT(*)
from #tbl_1 t1
LEFT JOIN #tbl_2 t2 on t1.HoleID = t2.HoleID AND (t1.GEOLFROM = t2.SAMPFROM)
LEFT JOIN #tbl_2 t3 on t1.HoleID = t3.HoleID AND (t1.GEOLTO = t3.SAMPTO)
WHERE t3.HoleID IS NOT NULL and t2.HoleID IS NOT NULL
```